# How to add module to webpack at runtime

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Say webpack have internal cache map to store fetched module, with following type (I never read webpack source, so this is based on my assumption)

```
Exports {
  [key: string]: any
}

CacheMap: {
  [modulePath: string]: Exports
}
```

The question is: How do I use this map, and add a dynamic module from code, so I can require it from other part of my code. Example

```
webpack.addToCache(moduleId, {
  default: function defaultExport() {},
  namedExport: function namedExport() {}
});
```

From other part of the bundle:

```
import MyDynamicModule, {namedExport} from 'moduleId';
```

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar to this, but not via webpack.

We import dynamic modules via a 'registry' that gets passed into our app where the registry is just a JS map where we set values in the map to be the different imported types that we want to have.

In your case you can have a registry that contains an array of objects where each object represents a custom type. You can identify them via a string name, or id or whatever. Something like this:

```
import foo, {bar} from 'FooBar';
const registry = {
  Foo: {componentType: foo, componentName:'Foo'},
  Bar: {componentType: bar, componentName:'Bar'} 
}
export registry
```

So now in your app you can import the registry and reference these types as registry.Foo and registry.Bar and you know that 'registry.Foo.componentType' is the real imported type.